# Unauthorized exception while connecting Neo4J using Neo4Jconfiguration with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

Hi I'm trying to write a micro service, I have create a simple spring boot application that extends with Neo4JConfiguration. I could run success and server started with the targeted port but by hitting the api the internal error throws in browser

Whitelabel Error Page
    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
    nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.ResultProcessingException: 
        Failed to execute request: 
        {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) WHERE id(n) = { id } RETURN collect(distinct p)",
            "parameters":{"id":1},"resultDataContents":["graph"]}]}
```

And my mvn console the error says clearly the session has not been authorized. Error :

```
12:12:19.114 [qtp212459676-16] INFO  org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession - There is no existing transaction, creating a transient one
12:12:19.272 [qtp212459676-16] INFO  o.n.o.session.request.DefaultRequest - POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) WHERE id(n) = { id } RETURN collect(distinct p)","parameters":{"id":1},"resultDataContents":["graph"]}]}
**caught response exception: Unauthorized**
12:12:19.606 [qtp212459676-16] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Intercepted exception
12:12:19.642 [qtp212459676-16] WARN  o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.ResultProcessingException: Failed to execute request: {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) WHERE id(n) = { id } RETURN collect(distinct p)","parameters":{"id":1},"resultDataContents":["graph"]}]}
```

Could anyone please tell me how to authorize the neo4j using springboot ?

Here is my bean connecting with Neo4J instance.

```
@Override
@Bean
public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
   // log.info("Initialising server connection");    
    return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474");
    //return new InProcessServer();
}

@Override
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    log.info("Initialising Session Factory");
    return new SessionFactory("nuclei.domain");
}

@Override
@Bean
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    log.info("Initialising session-scoped Session Bean");
    return super.getSession();
}
```

How can I set the username / password here ?

I appreciate If get the par solution of my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify them as system properties. See `org.neo4j.ogm.authentication.CredentialsService`; e.g. `-Dusername=neo4j -Dpassword=your_password`

Answer (score 3):

I got successfully connected with database now. Following are in the section I have added system properties.

```
@Override
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    log.info("Initialising Session Factory");
    System.setProperty("username", "neo4j");
    System.setProperty("password", "root");
    return new SessionFactory("nuclei.domain");
}
```

Need to add the credentials to sys properties before getting the session factory.For the good practice I brought back the credentials into my configuration file and loaded it to system properties.

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest version to date

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

enables you connect to Neo4j using any of the following methods

1.Passing connection credentials when opening the session

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("org.neo4j.example.domain");
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession("http://localhost:7474", username, password);
```

2.Embedding connection credentials in the URL

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("org.neo4j.example.domain");
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession("http://username:password@localhost:7474");
```

3.Setting System properties

```
System.setProperty("username", user);
System.setProperty("password", pass);
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("org.neo4j.example.domain");
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession("http://localhost:7474");
```

Comment: what is that example.domain?

Comment: 2nd option solved my problem, though it was required for me to change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`